# Clustering customer with string data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, string-metrics

I'm looking for a customer clustering solution. I have done a lot of research on the machine learning level to find algorithms that could fit my needs but I can't find much information when the data is mainly text.

I searched for clustering with string but found little relevant ( for me). Do you have any ideas for algorithms that could be used?

Type of relevant data :

- user right
- data
- protocol

Comment: There's an enormous literature on clustering algorithms, so I think this is too broad to answer in its current form.  I suggest you read some standard overview on clustering, examine common clustering algorithms, see whether they meet your needs, and then [edit] your question to state your requirements, identify which approaches you've already considered, and tell us why you rejected them (what requirements they fail to meet).  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking here, as there's little point in us repeating standard material that's widely available.

Comment: I may have found a lead that I'm going to explore. 
Separate the user rights in separate columns and replace the values with 0 or 1 ( or boolean).
I should be able to create groups based on rights.

I mainly look at algorithms like around kmeans. 
I also looked for string comparison with Hamming and Levenshtein distance.

I've done some research on the subject, but I can't find a lot of information on how to create customer groups, for example based on text data that can be quite diverse.